# Adding postgresql database import command to creation

Tags: sql, postgresql, import, schema, debian

This is my shell command for creating a database. It is run as part of a deployment script to automatically create two databases without human intervention.

```
# POSTGRES
apt-get install -y postgresql
echo "CREATE ROLE deploy LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$APP_DB_PASS';" | sudo -u postgres psql
su postgres -c "createdb db1 --owner deploy"
su postgres -c "createdb db2 --owner deploy"
service postgresql reload
```

Within this code, could someone please explain how I can integrate importing a SQL file into postgresql within this stage.

I believe it is something like this but I haven't go that to work:

```
psql --username=postgres < /etc/schema.sql
```

Comment: Launching `psql -U postgres` as a non-priviledged OS user assumes it can log in as a database superuser, which is not a default security policy. Why the inconsistency in using `sudo/su postgres` and then not using it?

Comment: Daniel, because I used code from various places and I am not completely sure what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

On debian, you probably need to follow Daniel's comment because PostgreSQL is probably configured to require the OS user to be the same username as the db user.

So you need to

```
su postgres -c "psql -f /etc/schema.sql"
```

Alternatively you could put all these db creation commands in a nice little shell script (without the su postgres -c part) and then just run that all at once.  Something like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "CREATE ROLE deploy LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$APP_DB_PASS';" | su postgres -c psql
 createdb db1 --owner deploy
 createdb db2 --owner deploy
 psql db1 -f /etc/schema.sql
 psql db2 -f /etc/schema.sql
```

Then you can run that with sudo or su -c and simplify the things that can go wrong, auth-wise.